# jQuery box fadeOut/fadeIn blinking after mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

How to make this just fade out on mouseover and just fade back in again on mouseleave?
[My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/villimagg/tvtUT/)

```
$(function() {
var box = $('#box');

box.on('mouseover', function() {
    box.fadeOut(500);
});
box.on('mouseleave', function() {
    box.fadeIn(500);
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#box').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tvtUT/9/)

Comment: yeah, this is more intelligent solution

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(function() {
    var box = $('#box');
    box.hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(500);

    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeIn(500);

    });
});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tvtUT/7/)